# What does substitute(substitute()) do?

Tags: r

I am not entirely sure I understand what `substitute` does, although I've used in it code before. Today I encountered in `shiny::exprToFunction` the following lines of code:

```
function (expr, env = parent.frame(2), quoted = FALSE, caller_offset = 1) 
{
    expr_sub <- eval(substitute(substitute(expr)), 
...
}
```

Can someone please explain why nested `substitute` is used here? A easy to run example would really help.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at

```
a<-function(aa) {
    b(aa)
}

b<-function(bb) {
    z(bb)   
}

z<-function(zz) {
    print(substitute(zz))
    print(substitute(substitute(zz)))
    print(eval(substitute(substitute(zz)), parent.frame()))
}

q<-5
a(q)
# bb
# substitute(bb)
# aa
```

The first/inner substitute grabs the name/symbol that was passed to the called function. The second/outer `substitute()` simply wraps a `substitute()` command around that discovered name/symbol. Then that `substitute()` is evaluated in the parent environment where it came from.

The method of using `substitute` to capture variable names only works when parameters are still promises; that is, they have not yet been evaluated.

Comment: I think you might have this backwards.  The outer substitute operates on the unevaluated expression `substitute(zz)` to produce the expression `substitute(bb)` which is then eval’d in the parent frame.  Same effect, but slightly different order of operations.