# When creating an alist, how to extract a function body at runtime

Tags: r, list

Quite new to R, I'm trying to find answers to this but maybe I'm not sure how to phrase the question, so sorry if this has been asked before.

I would like to fit a list of functions/models to data, in a for loop rather than manually doing each one. To do that, I need to specify the model in an `alist`, list the following:

```
flist <- alist(y ~ dnorm(mu, sigma),
               mu <- a + b*x,     # need to replace this line with general function
               a ~ dnorm(0, 100),
               b ~ dnorm(0, 10),
               sigma ~ dunif(0, 10)
)
```

To do that in a for loop, I would need to be able to replace `a + b*x` with the body of some function, chosen at runtime. So I was thinking of making it:

```
flist <- alist(y ~ dnorm(mu, sigma),
               mu <- body(function[i]),
               a ~ dnorm(0, 100),
               b ~ dnorm(0, 10),
               sigma ~ dunif(0, 10)
)
```

However, it seems like alist doesn't actually evaluate `body(function[i])`, which seems to be part of the point of `alist`. Is there a way to get the body out at runtime?

Essentially, what I'm after is for part of the expression in the alist to be evaluated (the body(...)), but not all of it (keeping the ~/<- operator unevaluated).

Is it possible to do this with `parse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand, but do you need something like this ?

```
funs <- list(f1 = function(x) x + 3, f2 = function(x) 2 * x + 2)


flist <- alist(y ~ dnorm(mu, sigma),
        mu <- FUN_BODY,     # need to replace this line with general function
        a ~ dnorm(0, 100),
        b ~ dnorm(0, 10),
        sigma ~ dunif(0, 10))


flist[[2]] <- eval(substitute(substitute(ARG,
  list(FUN_BODY = body(funs[[2]]))),
  list(ARG = flist[[2]])))

# [[1]]
# y ~ dnorm(mu, sigma)
# 
# [[2]]
# mu <- 2 * x + 2
# 
# [[3]]
# a ~ dnorm(0, 100)
# 
# [[4]]
# b ~ dnorm(0, 10)
# 
# [[5]]
# sigma ~ dunif(0, 10)
```

Comment: Thank you, this appears to work. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how the substitutions work.

Comment: This is not trivial and I can't really give you a crash course on `substitute` in a comment but the first `substitute` call replaces `ARG` by `flist[[2]]` which contains an expression figuring `FUN_BODY`, then the second call substitute `FUN_BODY` with `body(funs[[2]])`

Comment: maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30771626/what-does-substitutesubstitute-do

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `list` instead of `alist`. As you noticed, the whole point of `alist` is not to evaluate its arguments.
2. Don’t perform assignment. It’s unclear what the `mu <-` part is even supposed to do. Did you mean to use a named argument, or did you want to specify a dependent variable?

This might be what you want:

```
flist <- list(
    y ~ dnorm(mu, sigma),
    body(myfunction),
    a ~ dnorm(0, 100),
    b ~ dnorm(0, 10),
    sigma ~ dunif(0, 10)
)
```

But it’s unclear how this would be used. I think you probably want to use something like this instead of your second line:

```
mu ~ myfunction(somevar)
```

That is, you want a formula that is *using* `myfunction`.

Comment: mu is a dependent variable. I thought I need to explicitly state the relation that mu is equal to the value of the function. I'm using a package that comes with a book (one of the Bayesian Data Analysis books by Gelman et al...), and I believe that's what defines a `map` function (maximum a posteriori) that requires a list/alist to describe the functional relations and priors of the parameters.

Comment: @LimokPalantaemon See my edit. Anyway, specifying that a dependent variable is modelled by a relationship is quite fundamentally different from a variable assignment, so the `mu <- …` part would never have worked.

Comment: The `<-` was working for me when I directly input the expression. Previously I thought that `~` referred to something like "is drawn from [distribution to the right]", whereas I wanted mu to have a direct relation to the value of the function/expression. So I can use `~` for that as well?

Comment: In that case, if I use `mu ~ myfunction(somevars)` I come up to a different problem which I don't know how to solve. The issue is that there is a different number of arguments for each function (I'm actually fitting a series of i-order polynomials). So I was appending another alist to the above at runtime, with the correct number of parameters. However, I'm not sure how to apply that with the above solution. Essentially, what I'm after is for part of the expression in the alist to be evaluated, but not all of it.